# Blank page when serving react app with nginx in a specific location

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I have created a web application and now I am trying to deploy it with Nginx.
After developing the application I have created a production version with the command "npm run build".
Since NGINX I serve these files, the corresponding block is:
location / {
root /var/www/build
}

With this, my app works perfectly and I can access it through mydomain.com

The problem is that I want my application to be accessible via
mydomain.com/app

Since the address mydomain.com I want to reserve it to use it with wordpress and give SEO.

The thing is that when I change the NGINX configuration to
location / app {
root /var/www/build
}
gives 404 error.

Looking for the problem I found that the solution is
occasion /app {
aliases /var/www/build
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;
}

but with this change I get a blank page instead of my app. And if I inspect the page, the response is as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSOFg.png)

I have verified that in my browser I already have JavaScript enabled, so I don't understand what is going on.

Comment: Can you try going to `/app/` instead of `/app` with the trailing slash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a strong feeling your JavaScript files you have in your builds html file will result in a 404. Please check the Network Tab of your Browsers Developer Console. Entering this by pressing F12.

As your app is deployed under the `app` location but your JavaScript files are pointing to `/` they will never be found.

There are a million and one solution to solve this issue. Given you are using something like React.JS, Angular, Vue (Please make clear what kind of framework you are using) you should set `/app/` as your new base.

Check this https://skryvets.com/blog/2018/09/20/an-elegant-solution-of-deploying-react-app-into-a-subdirectory/. Great tutorial.

If you are using something not related to any framework you can use `<base>`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Comment: Thank you very much, it was just that